# 'Older Posts' link 404 in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, http-status-code-404

Currently working on a WordPress theme and the 'Older Posts' link seems to be pointing to the wrong URL after I have changed the permalink settings in the admin panel.

I have checked the .htaccess file and all the other links on the page are working correctly including the links to the individual posts pages and the categories links so it doesn't appear to be causing the issue.

Is this stored in the database somewhere as I am confused by this would still be pointing to the old location? Or could this be cached in some way?

Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: Please provide a few more details on how the 'older posts' link is being generated. What function is generating it? If you are creating a child theme, have you over-ridden the default function that does this? Also, is the link in the same structure as the permalink structure you've set? Is your .htaccess file changing when you make changes to the permalinks?

Answer (score 2):

Look for this line in your httpd.conf file under Apache in a WAMP set up

## LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Uncomment that (Remove # sign) this will allow for mod_rewrite rules to work.

Cheers

Comment: It appears to only be causing issues with the older posts link and this is happening even with the permalinks set to default where it shouldn't even need rewrite.